# Power of the Indian state to curtail access to "public" areas

Tags: india, indian-constitutional-law

I am not an expert on legal matters but wanted to ask the following question nevertheless: **to what extent can the Indian state curtail access for the public to its assets, specifically public institutions and areas**? More specifically, I noticed that institutions controlled by the government (such as several public universities) restrict access to their premises to the public at large (unless prior authorisation is obtained). Tourists (even domestic ones) are often charged a fee to enter the premises of monuments of historical importance and are refused entry otherwise. What is the legal basis of these practices? This comes in contrast to some countries (I've been informed of Germany as an example) where premises of public universities for instance cannot be locked out to the general public. To what extent are state assets *actually* public in India? Can the government arbitrarily create institutions and spaces where (physically) public access can be forbidden? Here, **I do not presuppose a situation where state intervention is necessary to uphold public order**, such as the eruption of violence in a specific area that requires blocking out access. Any references, suggestions for reading, or pointers to pertinent portions of the constitution would be appreciated as well.

Comment: A good place to start would be the **tort law relating to trespass** and the **constitutional right to property (article 300A).** which extends to public institutions as far as they are "juristic persons" in one way or another, although the state cannot discriminate in providing access to public places as per Article 15(2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### India is a country with a common law tradition.

That means, subject to the Constitution of the nation or the state, the relevant Parliament can pass and enforce any laws that it pleases. If they want to restrict access or charge a fee to access public land, they can.

I will note that there is a difference between publicly owned and publicly accessible. Military bases, police stations, and gaols are all publicly owned in India but they are not publicly accessible.

Comment: Would it not be better to qualify India's common law tradition with a statement of how much has been encoded, and how it is **similar to civil law jurisdictions** in at least this respect if not the overtly rational rather than precedent based disposition of judges in trial courts, and sometimes even in courts of record.